# Maven and Sonarqube

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, sonarqube, devops, cicd

A few basic questions on ci/cd pipelines.

1. When we build java code, do we create jar file before going for sonarqube analysis or does both happen simultaneously. My understanding is sonarqube analysis needs to be performed before maven build. Build should happen only if codequality crosses our quality checks.
2. Does sonar scanner and maven are used individually or sonar scanner is integrated with maven. I know both are possible but what is the best way that we need artifacts to be created only if code passes quality checks.
3. How does the sonarqube tell CI system (be it azuredevops or any other system) whether to go for next steps or break if the quality check is failed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Usually you run your full build (which contains building the jar file or in general artifacts) and the sonar analysis will be done afterwards (unit tests coverage, static code analysis etc.) and no it is not done before it's done afterwards otherwise it would not be possible to integrate results like code coverage of the unit/integration test into the sonarqube analysis.
2. Technically the sonar scanner can be triggered via the Maven build (it is done via a maven plugin) and often called like this: `mvn verify sonar:sonar`(assumed that it is configured correctly).
3. SonarQube has a webhook which will be called/triggered if the quality is not as expected. Most of the time the CI/CD system have a stage which will shows the result of that and makes the final result of the build "red". Also many source code hosting solutions (GitHub, GitLab, Gitea or alike) having indicators which shows that (usually) within a pull request...

*Update:*

- If you run sonar analysis on a project without compiling the code you will get this:

```
$ mvn clean sonar:sonar

[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.952 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-04T21:41:34+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project kata-fraction: 
Your project contains .java files, please provide compiled classes with sonar.java.binaries property, or exclude them from the analysis with sonar.exclusions property. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Comment: on your first point, sonarqube runs on source code and provides report based on source code and nothing to do with jar, right?

Comment: That's not fully correct because SonarQube needs the compiled classes (byte code analysis is easier than the real source code analysis). https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/overview/